# What calls the setSelected:NO method automatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have this weird problem with UITableView and UITableViewCell. Whenever the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called the setSelected:NO is called afterwards.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *cellData = dataSource[indexPath.row];

    NSString *cellId = nil;
    //choose cell type
    NSInteger type = [[cellData valueForKey:@"type"] integerValue];
    switch (type) {
        case 0:
            //root level
            cellId = @"rootHeaderCell";
            break;
        case 1:
            //sub header
            cellId = @"subHeaderCell";
            break;
        case 2:
        default:
            //value row - radiobutton
            cellId = @"radiobuttonCell";
            break;
    }

    CSBaseFilterCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    [cell setData:cellData];

    return cell;
}
```

`cellData` contains information about selection and in cell:

```
-(void)setData:(NSDictionary *)data {

NSLog(@"Set Data");
NSLog(@"data has selected=%d", [data hasKey:@"selected"]);
NSLog(@"data.selected=%@", [data valueForKey:@"selected"]);

    if ([data hasKey:@"selected"]) {
        [self setSelected:[[data valueForKey:@"selected"] boolValue]
                 animated:NO];

    }
}
```

I set the selection, but it was not selected. I've put traces in setData and the values were fine, I have put trace in `setSelected:animated:` and found that 3 calls are made:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    NSLog(@"%@ setSelected:selected=%d",self,selected);


    self.accessoryType = selected ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

this is what is displayed on log output:

```
2014-06-05 21:11:59.679 UITableView Filter Sort[42821:60b] Set Data
2014-06-05 21:11:59.679 UITableView Filter Sort[42821:60b] data has selected=1
2014-06-05 21:11:59.680 UITableView Filter Sort[42821:60b] data.selected=1
2014-06-05 21:11:59.680 UITableView Filter Sort[42821:60b] <CSRadioButtonCell: 0x8c80630; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 64; 320 32); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c76920>> setSelected:selected=1
2014-06-05 21:11:59.686 UITableView Filter Sort[42821:60b] <CSRadioButtonCell: 0x8c80630; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 64; 320 32); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c76920>> setSelected:selected=0
2014-06-05 21:11:59.811 UITableView Filter Sort[42821:60b] <CSRadioButtonCell: 0x8c80630; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 64; 320 32); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c76920>> setSelected:selected=0
```

Table is placed in the `ViewController`, it is not UITableViewController.

**UPDATE**
I have put the setData: call in `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and removed call to super definition of setSelected and this resolved the issue. It still shows in logs that setSelected is called with NO argument between setData in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` but at least willDisplay is last:)

I have also tried successfully with my own "selection" property `checked` which is set in `setData:` and in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: You could just set a breakpoint in there and find out. Regardless, using the visual state of the cell to keep your model information is a BAD idea.

Comment: as you can see from setData selection IS in model, what happens is that information from model is overridden by extra calls to setSelected: and I want to find out what is doing those calls

Comment: Thanks for the debugging feedback, very helpful.The extra calls to setSelected with NO are related to cell re-use (UITableView:prepareForReuse) and cell preparation for display (UITableView:_configureCellForDisplay).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do the setSelected in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: It behaves in the same way, when I scroll I can see briefly the tick but when appear animation stops tick is gone. When I removed call to [super setSelected:selected animated:animated]; then it started to work. However this doesnt points why setSelected is called many times with `NO` argument.

Comment: I ended up with approach using custom `checked` property, because if I removed call to `super` I was unable to toggle this property like `selected = !selected` anymore (at least it is in Swift so)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in PDTSimpleCalendar where the current selected date would not show anymore in ios15, it worked fine in ios14. Breakpoints show that there's an extra call to setSelected with the value false, right after setSelected is called with the value true!

Getting rid of the setSelected call on super fixed it.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    // [super setSelected:selected];
    [self setCircleColor:self.isToday selected:selected];
}
```